# If $\int_{\frac{\pi}{6}}^{\frac{\pi}{3}}\frac{3\tan^2x+6\tan x+11}{1+\tan ^2x}dx=\frac{k\pi+\lambda}{6}$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

If $$\int_{\frac{\pi}{6}}^{\frac{\pi}{3}}\frac{3\tan^2x+6\tan x+11}{1+\tan ^2x}dx=\frac{k\pi+\lambda}{6}$$,then the value of $(k+\lambda)$ is
$$(A)10\hspace{1cm}(B)12\hspace{1cm}(C)14\hspace{1cm}(D)16$$

---

My Attempt:
Let $$I=\int_{\frac{\pi}{6}}^{\frac{\pi}{3}}\frac{3\tan^2x+6\tan x+11}{1+\tan ^2x}dx.......................(1)$$
Applying $$\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx=\int_{a}^{b}f(a+b-x)dx$$
$$I=\int_{\frac{\pi}{6}}^{\frac{\pi}{3}}\frac{3\cot^2x+6\cot x+11}{1+\cot ^2x}dx$$
$$I=\int_{\frac{\pi}{6}}^{\frac{\pi}{3}}\frac{3+6\tan x+11\tan^2x}{1+\tan ^2x}dx...........(2)$$
Add $(1)$ and $2$ to get
$$2I=\int_{\frac{\pi}{6}}^{\frac{\pi}{3}}\frac{14+12\tan x+14\tan^2x}{1+\tan ^2x}dx=\int_{\frac{\pi}{6}}^{\frac{\pi}{3}}14+\frac{12\tan x}{1+\tan ^2x}dx$$
$$I=\int_{\frac{\pi}{6}}^{\frac{\pi}{3}}7+\frac{6\tan x\sec^2x}{(1+\tan ^2x)^2}dx$$
$$I=\frac{7\pi}{6}+3\int_{\frac{1}{\sqrt3}}^{\sqrt3}\frac{2tdt}{(1+t^2)^2}$$
$$I=\frac{7\pi}{6}+3\int_{\frac{4}{3}}^{4}\frac{dp}{p^2}=\frac{7\pi}{6}-3(4-\frac{4}{3})=\frac{7\pi}{6}-8=\frac{7\pi-48}{6}$$

So $k+\lambda=-41$,but the answer given is $16$.

Where have i gone wrong?Please help me.Thanks.

Comment: mistake in  evaluating $\int\frac{dp}{p^2}$

Comment: $$\int_{\frac{\pi}{6}}^{\frac{\pi}{3}}\frac{3\tan^2(x)+6\tan(x)+11}{1+\tan^2(x)}\space\text{d}x=$$
$$\int_{\frac{\pi}{6}}^{\frac{\pi}{3}}\left(3\sin(2x)+8\cos^2(x)+3\right)\space\text{d}x=$$
$$3\int_{\frac{\pi}{6}}^{\frac{\pi}{3}}\sin(2x)\space\text{d}x+8\int_{\frac{\pi}{6}}^{\frac{\pi}{3}}\cos^2(x)\space\text{d}x+3\int_{\frac{\pi}{6}}^{\frac{\pi}{3}}1\space\text{d}x$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $$I = \int\frac{3\tan^2 x+6\tan x+11}{1+\tan^2 x}dx = 3\int\frac{1+\tan^2 x}{1+\tan^2 x}dx+\int\frac{6\tan x+8}{1+\tan^2 x}dx$$

So $$I = 3x+6\int \sin x\cos xdx+8\int \cos^2 xdx$$

So $$I = 3x+3\int \sin 2xdx+4\int (1+\cos 2x)dx = 3x-\frac{3}{2}\cos 2x+4x+2\sin 2x$$

So we Get $$I = 7x-\frac{3}{2}\cos 2x+2\sin 2x$$

Now $$\int_{\frac{\pi}{6}}^{\frac{\pi}{3}}\frac{3\tan^2 x+6\tan x+11}{1+\tan^2 x}dx = \frac{7\pi}{6}-\frac{3}{2}\left[-\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{2}\right]+2\left[0\right]=\frac{7\pi}{6}+\frac{3}{2}$$

So we Get $$ = \frac{7\pi+9}{6} = \frac{k\pi+\lambda}{6}$$

So we get $$k+\lambda = 7+9 = 16$$